# How to use Excel to open a new URL in an opened Chrome tab without opening a new tab

Tags: vba, google-chrome, url, excel

I have two buttons in an Excel spreadsheet.  When I click button1, Chrome starts a new tab, but when I click button2, Chrome will open another tab.

What I want is when I click button2, the Chrome tab opened with button1 will visit button2's URL by refreshing the URL in the first tab, not creating a new tab.  Thanks!

```
Private Sub Button1_Click()
    chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    Shell (chromePath & " -url http:abc.com")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    chromePath = """C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
    Shell (chromePath & " -url http:def.com")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Selenium VBA](https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/). Perhaps using the switchTo() method could set Selenium's focus to an open Chrome window, which could then be automated as usual with the other Selenium methods.